# .Net Framework Web Api Works in WebDeploy but not in Manual Publish

Tags: c#, .net, iis

We have a web api in dotnet framework 4.8, when we deploy the web service to server with web deploy it works perfectly fine. But when we try manual publish in local and then copy the files to server, it does'nt work.
To identity when I did manual publish in local system and then used IIS from my local machine to check, I got below error, But on server I have no idea whats going on.
Let me know someone has any lead.

Thank You in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please use registry keys to compare the IIS components installed on the two machines (your local and the server) and the result should reveal what's wrong. Very likely you missed some.

Answer (score 0):

The 500.21 Error occurs because .NET Framework 4.0 configuration for ASP.NET has been damaged. You should repair the 4.0.30319 version.

You can do it by command prompt or use the Repair tool: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698555

To repair by command prompt, open CMD (Administrator) and type:

`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all`

Restart IIS.